# Black screen, no cursor, no WIFI no GUI, on pressing Left Shift button command line opens

Tags: boot

I am not very familiar with Ubuntu, so I found that my WIFI icon disappeared and was disconnected too from internet.
After restarting I ran into ACPI error and the system was not booting.
Now if I press left shift button I got three choices I clicked the first one -Ubuntu, and it led me to command line.
I checked if I could connect to internet from here but unable to.I am nervous and unable to think
I will not be able to share here what is showing on my Ubuntu PC, posting from a different PC.

Edit: I gained access to internet by using instructions in an online resource. My senior at work remotely accessed my machine and did some restoration and was able to login
I was still worried that all might not be well yet.
I have suspended the PC after work and now facing issues with it. even if the laptop is left idle for some time, the laptop is stuck(not shutdown)
I have hard reboot again, no prompt for relogging-in

Edit: I was left with no option but reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: did you change anything before the wifi icon disappeared?

Comment: Yes I had uninstalled some Qt packages
My senior at work remotely accessed my machine. Before this I had to do a lot of steps to even get the internet working. I don't know what he did I was able to login but now having issues with suspend, does not wake up prompt for login